# latex/overleaf table number start from 2

Tags: tables, numbering

I am suffering from the numbering issue. The first table in my thesis start numbering from 1, which I have not idea why. I have tried longtable package, but it didn't work out in somehow. I use overleaf platform.

thank you all for the help in advance.

```
\begin{table}[H]
\resizebox{\textwidth}{22mm}{
\centering
\caption{Summary of the data collection}
\label{table:data collection}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}

\toprule
\multirow{2}{12em}{\diagbox[width=11em,height=2.5em]{Participant}{Condition}}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Periodic} & Aperiodic \\ \cline{2-4}
  & without silence      & with silence     & with silence           \\ 
\midrule
1 & \checked & \checked & \checked \\ 
2 & \checked & \checked & -  \\ 
3 & \checked & \checked & -  \\ 
4 & \checked & \checked & -  \\ 
\bottomrule
\footnote{
Periodic condition: target stimuli is presented in the fifth position.\\
Aperiodic condition: target stimuli is presented in a random position.\\
without silence: there is not 100 ms silence after each stimuli. \\
with silence: there is a 100 ms silence after each stimuli.}
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! The problem might be that the `\label` command is too far away from the `\caption`, you could try putting the label directly after the caption. If that doesn't work then presumably you have some statement in the code before the table that sets the table counter to two. You didn't post that code, so we can't see if that is actually the case. You could try to make a small example document with the documentclass, the packages, and only the table in it, and check if the error still occurs. If not, then start adding content before the table until the issue appears.

Comment: Then, post the code that produces the issue here in the question in full (using the `edit` button at the bottom of the post).

Comment: don't use \resizebox like this. Don't you get errors from it?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thank you for pointing it out. the document can be recompiled with \resizebox but it might affected the size in somehow, which I dont know

Comment: well I know.  And I tell you: don't use it. You get errors and even if tex recovers and you get some output it is more or less random.

Comment: thank you, I removed it and the documents look better. but seems the numbering issue still not solved:(

Comment: @Marijn thank you for your answer. It didn't change after I moved the \label directly after the caption. but the number did start from 1 when I put it int a new example document, which is very motivating! I checked the original documents, this is the first table I set. Before that, there are some figures but no tables.

Comment: @user226555 you can also try the opposite troubleshooting technique, start from your full document (where the issue occurs), and remove step by step elements from the document while recompiling after every step, until you end up with a fully minimal document with only this table. At one of those steps the issue will be resolved, then you know which piece of code is responsible for the problem.

Comment: none  of `\centering` . `\caption` or `\footnote` can be used inside `\resizebox` you surely must get an error from this? It is best to avoid resizing tables in any case.

Comment: @Marijn the number only changed to one after I deleted everything but the table, now I put \setcounter{table}{0}  before this table, kind of solved the problem, the number start to count from one though

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I dont really know, but it can recompile the document in overleaf at least

Comment: @user226555 if the number changed only when you deleted everything except the table then that means that the problem was in the last piece of code that you deleted. What was that code?

Comment: @Marijn the last piece of code is just characters, I am thinking the problem might be on the final complied .text instead of the single part, since there is a error message from below code.
```
\newpage
\listoftables
\newpage
\begin{singlespacing}
% print the glossary (list of acronyms)
\renewcommand{\glsnamefont}[1]{\textbf{#1}}
\printnoidxglossary[
type=\acronymtype,style=long]
\end{singlespacing}
```

Comment: Can you compile it without getting a red circle showing an error? After _any_ tex error the pdf is at most usable for debugging it does not have usable output.  But if you show no test document and only show a fragment that will generate multiple unrelated errors it is really hard for anyone to help you at all.

Comment: using `\resizebox` at all n tables is  to be avoided but really don't do `\resizebox{\textwidth}{22mm}`  you are using different scale factors in each direction, this will distort the font and make the table unreadable.

Comment: @user226555 in LaTeX every piece of code involved in a document can influence every other piece of code that comes after it (and sometimes even before it), so you need to consider packages and contents of files added with `\input` and `\include`, both ways (from the main file to subfiles and the other way around). Then the same debugging techniques apply, either start from a single piece of code and add other code around it, where this other code can also be contained in different files, or start from the full document and remove peices of code, from all files involved.

Comment: And furthermore follow the advice of David above, if you have an error in some other part of the document you should not continue compiling the document, first fix the error and then try to fix the issue if it is still there. In LaTeX errors can propagate and lead to strange results elsewhere, therefore fixing any errors should be the first priority for solving issues such as this.